# SQL Server Find Index Definitions

Tags: sql-server, indexing, definition

SQL Server Find Index Definitions
I am tasked to migrate a set of tables schema, content, and table objects to an Azure SQLdb. I ran in to a problem where triggers and indexes. They didn't get copied over. Triggers were easy to get from the sys.modules table but no luck with indexes.

Comment: How were you copying the other schema objects?

Answer (score 2):

I had no luck finding anything here or on the interwebs so I wrote this. I hope this helps someone.

```
/*

========================WARNING!!!!!!!!================================

The follow has the following defaults that may not suite your needs.
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF        I leave this on Since my TempDB has the room,
                            bandwidth, and it's own IO channel.
                            It's up to you though.
ONLINE = OFF
Created  ON [PRIMARY]

Created by: Frank Canapa
Date 2020-07-24
Based on the work of others on the interwebs

*/


;WITH MyCTE
AS
(
SELECT T = t.[name]
,A = 'ALTER TABLE [' + schema_name(t.schema_id) + '].[' + t.[name]+'] ADD CONSTRAINT [' + i.[name] + '] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (' + substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1)
, B =')WITH (PAD_INDEX = ' +
CASE WHEN i.[is_padded] = 0 THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN i.[is_padded] = 1 THEN 'ON' 
END 
, C =', STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF' + ', SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF' + ', IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ' +
CASE WHEN i.[IGNORE_DUP_KEY] = 0 THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN i.[IGNORE_DUP_KEY] = 1 THEN 'ON'
END
, D = ', ONLINE = OFF' + ', ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ' +
CASE WHEN i.[ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS] = 0 THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN i.[ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS] = 1 THEN 'ON'
END 
, E = ', ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ' +
CASE WHEN i.[ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS] = 0 THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN i.[ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS] = 1 THEN 'ON'
END 
, F = CASE WHEN i.[fill_factor]  = 0 THEN ''
        WHEN i.[fill_factor] > 0 THEN ', FILLFACTOR = ' + CAST(i.[fill_factor] AS varchar(3)) 
END 
, G =  ') ON [PRIMARY]'
    FROM sys.objects t
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes i
            ON t.object_id = i.object_id
        CROSS APPLY(SELECT col.[name] + ', '
                        FROM sys.index_columns ic
                            INNER JOIN sys.columns col
                                ON ic.object_id = col.object_id
                                AND ic.column_id = col.column_id
                        WHERE ic.object_id = t.object_id
                        AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
                        ORDER by key_ordinal
                        for xml path ('') ) D (column_names)
    WHERE i.[is_primary_key] = 1
    AND t.is_ms_shipped <> 1
    AND index_id > 0

UNION

SELECT T = t.[name]
,A = 'CREATE ' +
CASE WHEN i.[type] = 1 THEN 'CLUSTERED'
    WHEN i.[type] = 2 THEN 'NONCLUSTERED'
    WHEN i.[type] = 3 THEN 'XML'
    WHEN i.[type] = 4 THEN 'Spatial '
    WHEN i.[type] = 5 THEN 'Clustered columnstore'
    WHEN i.[type] = 6 THEN 'Nonclustered columnstore'
    WHEN i.[type] = 7 THEN 'Nonclustered hash'
    END
, B = ' INDEX  [' + i.[name] + '] ON ['+ schema_name(t.schema_id) + '].[' + t.[name]+'] ('+substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1) + ')WITH (PAD_INDEX = ' +
CASE WHEN i.[is_padded] = 0 THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN i.[is_padded] = 1 THEN 'ON' 
END 
, C = ', STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF' + ', SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF' + ', IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ' +
CASE WHEN i.[IGNORE_DUP_KEY] = 0 THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN i.[IGNORE_DUP_KEY] = 1 THEN 'ON'
END
, D = ', ONLINE = OFF' + ', ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ' +
CASE WHEN i.[ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS] = 0 THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN i.[ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS] = 1 THEN 'ON'
END 
, E = ', ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ' +
CASE WHEN i.[ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS] = 0 THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN i.[ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS] = 1 THEN 'ON'
END 
, F = CASE WHEN i.[fill_factor]  = 0 THEN ''
        WHEN i.[fill_factor] > 0 THEN ', FILLFACTOR = ' + CAST(i.[fill_factor] AS varchar(3))
END 
, G = ') ON [PRIMARY]'
    FROM sys.objects t
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes i
            ON t.object_id = i.object_id
        CROSS APPLY(SELECT col.[name] + ', '
                        FROM sys.index_columns ic
                            INNER JOIN sys.columns col
                                ON ic.object_id = col.object_id
                                AND ic.column_id = col.column_id
                        WHERE ic.object_id = t.object_id
                        AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
                        ORDER by key_ordinal
                        for xml path ('') ) D (column_names)
    WHERE i.[is_primary_key] = 0
    AND substring(i.[name],1,1 ) != '_'
    AND t.is_ms_shipped <> 1
    AND index_id > 0
)
SELECT  T, A + B + C + D + E + F + G
    FROM MyCTE
    ORDER BY T
```

Comment: Just one addon. It is good to change that part "SELECT col.[name] + ', '" to "SELECT '[' + col.[name] + '], '" in order to support column names which are reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

A small change in the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63082120/10965132) to separate the main fields and included fields.

Before:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX  [nci_tbl_tbl_Table_RouteRace_id] ON [dbo].[tbl_Table] (DeliveryTransaction_id, StorageObject_id, RouteRace_id) WITH ... ON [PRIMARY]
```

After:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX  [nci_tbl_tbl_Table_RouteRace_id] ON [dbo].[tbl_Table] (RouteRace_id ASC) INCLUDE (DeliveryTransaction_id, StorageObject_id) WITH ... ON [PRIMARY]
```

Modified sql script:

```
;WITH MyCTE
AS
(
SELECT T = t.[name]
,A = 'ALTER TABLE [' + schema_name(t.schema_id) + '].[' + t.[name]+'] ADD CONSTRAINT [' + i.[name] + '] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (' + substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1)
+isnull('INCLUDE('+ substring(column_names2, 1, len(column_names2)-1)+')','')

,B = ') WITH (PAD_INDEX = ' +
CASE WHEN i.[is_padded] = 0 THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN i.[is_padded] = 1 THEN 'ON' 
END 
, C =', STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF' + ', SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF' + ', IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ' +
CASE WHEN i.[IGNORE_DUP_KEY] = 0 THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN i.[IGNORE_DUP_KEY] = 1 THEN 'ON'
END
, D = ', ONLINE = OFF' + ', ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ' +
CASE WHEN i.[ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS] = 0 THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN i.[ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS] = 1 THEN 'ON'
END 
, E = ', ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ' +
CASE WHEN i.[ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS] = 0 THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN i.[ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS] = 1 THEN 'ON'
END 
, F = CASE WHEN i.[fill_factor]  = 0 THEN ''
        WHEN i.[fill_factor] > 0 THEN ', FILLFACTOR = ' + CAST(i.[fill_factor] AS varchar(3)) 
END 
, G =  ') ON [PRIMARY]'
    FROM sys.objects t
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes i
            ON t.object_id = i.object_id
        CROSS APPLY(SELECT col.[name] + iif(ic.is_descending_key=1,' DESC',' ASC') + ', '
                        FROM sys.index_columns ic
                            INNER JOIN sys.columns col
                                ON ic.object_id = col.object_id
                                AND ic.column_id = col.column_id
                        WHERE ic.object_id = t.object_id
                        AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
                        and ic.is_included_column = 0
                        ORDER by key_ordinal
                        for xml path ('') ) D (column_names)

        CROSS APPLY(SELECT col.[name] + ', '
                        FROM sys.index_columns ic
                            INNER JOIN sys.columns col
                                ON ic.object_id = col.object_id
                                AND ic.column_id = col.column_id
                        WHERE ic.object_id = t.object_id
                        AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
                        and ic.is_included_column = 1
                        ORDER by key_ordinal
                        for xml path ('') ) Dinclided (column_names2)

    WHERE i.[is_primary_key] = 1
    AND t.is_ms_shipped <> 1
    AND index_id > 0

UNION

SELECT T = t.[name]
,A = 'CREATE ' +
CASE WHEN i.[type] = 1 THEN 'CLUSTERED'
    WHEN i.[type] = 2 THEN 'NONCLUSTERED'
    WHEN i.[type] = 3 THEN 'XML'
    WHEN i.[type] = 4 THEN 'Spatial '
    WHEN i.[type] = 5 THEN 'Clustered columnstore'
    WHEN i.[type] = 6 THEN 'Nonclustered columnstore'
    WHEN i.[type] = 7 THEN 'Nonclustered hash'
    END
, B = ' INDEX  [' + i.[name] + '] ON ['+ schema_name(t.schema_id) + '].[' + t.[name]+'] ('+substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1) + ')'
+isnull('INCLUDE('+ substring(column_names2, 1, len(column_names2)-1)+')','')+
+ ' WITH (PAD_INDEX = ' +
CASE WHEN i.[is_padded] = 0 THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN i.[is_padded] = 1 THEN 'ON' 
END 
, C = ', STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF' + ', SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF' + ', IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ' +
CASE WHEN i.[IGNORE_DUP_KEY] = 0 THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN i.[IGNORE_DUP_KEY] = 1 THEN 'ON'
END
, D = ', ONLINE = OFF' + ', ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ' +
CASE WHEN i.[ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS] = 0 THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN i.[ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS] = 1 THEN 'ON'
END 
, E = ', ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ' +
CASE WHEN i.[ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS] = 0 THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN i.[ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS] = 1 THEN 'ON'
END 
, F = CASE WHEN i.[fill_factor]  = 0 THEN ''
        WHEN i.[fill_factor] > 0 THEN ', FILLFACTOR = ' + CAST(i.[fill_factor] AS varchar(3))
END 
, G = ') ON [PRIMARY]'
    FROM sys.objects t
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes i
            ON t.object_id = i.object_id
        CROSS APPLY(SELECT col.[name] + iif(ic.is_descending_key=1,' DESC',' ASC') + ', '
                        FROM sys.index_columns ic
                            INNER JOIN sys.columns col
                                ON ic.object_id = col.object_id
                                AND ic.column_id = col.column_id
                        WHERE ic.object_id = t.object_id
                        AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
                        and ic.is_included_column = 0

                        ORDER by key_ordinal
                        for xml path ('') ) D (column_names)

        CROSS APPLY(SELECT col.[name] + ', '
                        FROM sys.index_columns ic
                            INNER JOIN sys.columns col
                                ON ic.object_id = col.object_id
                                AND ic.column_id = col.column_id
                        WHERE ic.object_id = t.object_id
                        AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
                        and ic.is_included_column = 1
                        ORDER by key_ordinal
                        for xml path ('') ) Dinclided (column_names2)

    WHERE i.[is_primary_key] = 0
    AND substring(i.[name],1,1 ) != '_'
    AND t.is_ms_shipped <> 1
    AND index_id > 0
)
SELECT  T, A + B + C + D + E + F + G
    FROM MyCTE
    ORDER BY T
```